# Do we need AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to initialize beans?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am using `Spring 4.3.0 annotation with java config` and i made a small Spring MVC web project . I was trying to use the `@Autowire` annotation in my @Controller which works perfectly fine . But this dosen't work in @Service or @Repository

Code for **@Controller** :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController 
{   
  @Autowired
  private EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;     //works perfectly fine

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

  private AuthenticationService authenticationService = AuthenticationService.getAuthenticationInstance();

  @RequestMapping(value = "/login.jsp" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView userLoginPage(){
   return new ModelAndView("Login");        
  }
}
```

**@Service** class

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService 
{
   @Autowired
   private EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;   // this gives NULL

   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationService.class);

   private static AuthenticationService authenticationService;

   LoginDao loginDao = LoginDao.getLoginInstance();

   private boolean firstTimeLogin = false;

   public static AuthenticationService getAuthenticationInstance(){
       if(authenticationService == null)
           authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
       return authenticationService;
   } 
}
```

**@Configuration** class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "programs.examples")
public class AppConfig
{
   @Bean
   public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
       UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new ChainableUrlBasedViewResolver();
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       resolver.setOrder(0);
       return resolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver jspViewResolver2() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view2/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       resolver.setOrder(1);
       return resolver;
      }

   @Bean                       // @Component is used with EmployeeInfo
   public EmployeeInfo employeeInfo(){    
     return new EmployeeInfo();
   }
}
```

Also if i can initialize the bean without **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext** in `@Controller` , then do we really need `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

This was a very naive question , so if anyone dosen't understand like me , here is the answer :

Autowiring was working in @Controller but not in @Service , because i initialized service object manually with `new` , so automatic initialization won't work in @Service class

Regarding `ApplicationAnnotation` we don't need that since beans are initialized at startup via component scan which is the whole point of spring

Comment: You're missing the whole point of dependency injection, which is to let the container (spring) inject the dependencies, rather than creating them by yourself using new. That's what makes your code testable, allows spring to intercept the method calls, etc.

Comment: i get your point , i am too naive for spring , just wanted to clearify my doubts

Comment: RootContext Configuration ( Component, Service, Repository )  and ApplicationContext Configuration = AppConfig (Controller) .... employeeInfo belongs to RootContext.

Comment: i didnt get you